# Use of Keras Sparse Categorical Crossentropy for pixel-wise multi-class classification

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, loss-function

I'll start by disclosing that I'm a machine learning and Keras novice and don't know much beyond general CNN binary classifiers. I'm trying to perform pixelwise multi-class classification using a U-Net architecture (TF backend) on many 256x256 images. In other words, I input a 256x256 image, and I want it to output a 256x256 "mask" (or label image) where the values are integers from 0-30 (each integer represents a unique class). I'm training on 2 1080Ti NVIDIA GPUs.

When I attempt to perform one-hot encoding, I get an OOM error, which is why I'm using sparse categorical cross entropy as my loss function instead of regular categorical cross entropy. However, when training my U-Net, my loss value is "nan" from start to finish (it initializes as nan and never changes). When I normalize my "masks" by dividing all values by 30 (so they go from 0-1), I get ~0.97 accuracy, which I'm guessing is because most of the labels in my image are 0 (and it's just outputting a bunch of 0s).

Here's the U-Net I'm using:

```
def unet(pretrained_weights = None,input_size = (256,256,1)):
inputs = keras.engine.input_layer.Input(input_size)
conv1 = Conv2D(64, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(inputs)
conv1 = Conv2D(64, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv1)
pool1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv1)
conv2 = Conv2D(128, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(pool1)
conv2 = Conv2D(128, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv2)
pool2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv2)
conv3 = Conv2D(256, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(pool2)
conv3 = Conv2D(256, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv3)
pool3 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv3)
conv4 = Conv2D(512, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(pool3)
conv4 = Conv2D(512, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv4)
#drop4 = Dropout(0.5)(conv4)
drop4 = SpatialDropout2D(0.5)(conv4)
pool4 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(drop4)

conv5 = Conv2D(1024, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(pool4)
conv5 = Conv2D(1024, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv5)
#drop5 = Dropout(0.5)(conv5)
drop5 = SpatialDropout2D(0.5)(conv5)

up6 = Conv2D(512, 2, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(UpSampling2D(size = (2,2))(drop5))
merge6 = concatenate([drop4,up6], axis = 3)
conv6 = Conv2D(512, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(merge6)
conv6 = Conv2D(512, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv6)

up7 = Conv2D(256, 2, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(UpSampling2D(size = (2,2))(conv6))
merge7 = concatenate([conv3,up7], axis = 3)
conv7 = Conv2D(256, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(merge7)
conv7 = Conv2D(256, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv7)

up8 = Conv2D(128, 2, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(UpSampling2D(size = (2,2))(conv7))
merge8 = concatenate([conv2,up8], axis = 3)
conv8 = Conv2D(128, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(merge8)
conv8 = Conv2D(128, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv8)

up9 = Conv2D(64, 2, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(UpSampling2D(size = (2,2))(conv8))
merge9 = concatenate([conv1,up9], axis = 3)
conv9 = Conv2D(64, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(merge9)
conv9 = Conv2D(64, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv9)
conv9 = Conv2D(32, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv9)
conv10 = Conv2D(1, 1, activation = 'softmax')(conv9)
#conv10 = Flatten()(conv10)
#conv10 = Dense(65536, activation = 'softmax')(conv10)
flat10 = Reshape((65536,1))(conv10)
#conv10 = Conv1D(1, 1, activation='linear')(conv10)

model = Model(inputs = inputs, outputs = flat10)

opt = Adam(lr=1e-6,clipvalue=0.01)
model.compile(optimizer = opt, loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['sparse_categorical_accuracy'])
#model.compile(optimizer = Adam(lr = 1e-6), loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])
#model.compile(optimizer = Adam(lr = 1e-4),

#model.summary()

if(pretrained_weights):

    model.load_weights(pretrained_weights)

return model
```

Note that I needed to flatten the output just to get sparse categorical cross entropy to function properly (it didn't like my 2D matrix for some reason).

And here's an example of a training run (just 1 epoch because it's the same no matter how many I run)

```
model = unet()
model.fit(x=x_train, y=y_train, batch_size=1, epochs=1, verbose=1, validation_split=0.2, shuffle=True)
```

Train on 2308 samples, validate on 577 samples
Epoch 1/1
2308/2308 [==============================] - 191s 83ms/step - loss: nan - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9672 - val_loss: nan - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9667
Out[18]:

Let me know if more information is needed to diagnose the problem. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hey I have the same problem now and with the two solutions below am having shape error with target and output. Did you get this resolved?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that for multiclass classification, you need to output a vector with one dimension per category, which represents the confidence in that category. If you want to identify 30 different classes, then your final layer should be a 3D tensor, (256, 256, 30).

```
conv10 = Conv2D(30, 1, activation = 'softmax')(conv9)
flat10 = Reshape((256*256*30,1))(conv10)

opt = Adam(lr=1e-6,clipvalue=0.01)
model.compile(optimizer = opt, loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics = 
['sparse_categorical_accuracy'])
```

I'm assuming that your input is a (256, 256, 1) float tensor with values between 0 and 1, and your target is a (256*256) Int tensor.

Does that help?

Comment: I was under the impression that's only the case for regular categorical cross entropy where you need one-hot encoding (and thus a 256x256x30 output). From the limited information available on sparse categorical cross entropy, it seems like you don't need one-hot encoding, which would resolve my memory error. Is that definitely not the case?

Comment: Sparse categorical crossentropy takes a sparse target, but it doesn't take a sparse prediction, but takes a dense tensor for the prediction. Just try it.

Comment: If you need a lot more memory, you can resize your images to 224x224 (which is a more common size for CNNs than 256x256), or you can remove the centermost layers of the U-net, which take up the most size.

Comment: @TaoLin i tried the same thing with image(256,256,1) and target to be(256*256)  but I am getting shape error between target and output. because target is (65536) and output is (65536*30). Any help on how these shapes should be?

Answer (score 1):

```
conv10 = Conv2D(nclasses, kernel_size=(1, 1))(up9)
out = BatchNormalization()(conv10)
out = Reshape((img_height*img_width, nclasses), input_shape=(img_height, img_width, nclasses))(out)
out = Activation('softmax')(out)


model = Model(inputs=[inputs], outputs=[out])
model.compile(optimizer = Adam(lr = 1e-4), loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['sparse_categorical_accuracy'])
```

x_train :(batch_size, 224, 224, 3) float32 (Input images)
y_train: (batch_size, 50176, 1) uint8 (Target labels)

The above code seems to work for **multi-class segmentation** (nclasses), where target labels are **not one hot encoded**. One hot encoding creates memory issues if your data size and/or model is very large.

The last layer has shape (None, 50176, 16) (since nclasses=16, None corr to batch). The elements in labels have value **0 - (nclasses-1)**.

Using **argmax** on class index(-1) and **reshaping** the output outside seems to be the trick, in case you want a corr. image output ...

**NB:** Sparse Categorical Entropy seems to have issues in **keras 2.2.2** and above !!!

Comment: hi, I did the same as you suggested. having my target shape to be (65536,1) and last layer to be(65536,9). but I am experiencing tensor shape error. I cannot find an implementation of sparse entropy anywhere. can you suggest me where it went wrong

Answer (score 1):

It seems now that you can simply do `softmax` activation on the last `Conv2D` layer and then specify `categorical_crossentropy` loss and train on the image without any reshaping tricks. I've tested with a dummy dataset and it works well. Try it ~ !

```py
inp = keras.Input(...)
# define your model here
out = keras.layers.Conv2D(classes, (1, 1), activation='softmax') (...)
model = keras.Model(inputs=[inp], outputs=[out], name='unet')
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                      optimizer='adam',
                      metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(tensor4d, tensor4d)
```

You can also compile using `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` and then train with output of shape `(samples, height, width)` where each pixel in the output corresponds to a class label: `model.fit(tensor4d, tensor3d)`

PS. I use `keras` from `tensorflow.keras` (tensorflow 2)

Answer (score 0):

OOM:

Make a custom function to derive one-hot encoding instead of using a predefined function like "to_categorical".

It takes 1/4th the amount of memory (in my case).

[image]