# How to prepare targets for Sparse categorical entropy

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, mask, loss-function

I want to performing multiclass semantic segmentation. My images are grayscale.

```
image:(256,256,1)
```

I tried one hot encoding for multiclass segmentation and it works. The shape of my mask or target looks like this after one hot encoding. I have 8 classes.

```
mask:(256,256,8)
```

But one hot encoding is causing me memory error since my GPU cannot handle it and so I need to switch to another loss function which is **sparse_categorical_crossentropy**. But I am not sure how to encode my target for this.
I read that sparse entropy has only integer targets. I labelled my class names in categories such as 'defect1', 'defect2', 'defect3' etc.

But how do i encode my target labels for this entropy. Is it just a single list of target values? How should it look like when i feed it into the network?
Is there any particular encoding method to perform this? or any example of how the target should look like?

I am creating the dataset of images and target myself(custom dataset) so I did the annotations and labelled it. I am using U-net architecture.

I tried having my target to be `(256,256)`
and last layer with `out=layers.Conv2D(9,1,activation='softmax')(previous_layer)`. 9 is the number of classes. With this i am getting shape error

```
valueError: Error while checking target:expected output to have 4 dimensions but got array with shape (None,256,256).
```

[I tried also the answers in the following link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54136325/use-of-keras-sparse-categorical-crossentropy-for-pixel-wise-multi-class-classifi)

So kept target shape to be `(256*256,1)`  and used reshaping of last layer.

```
out=layers.Conv2D(9,1,activation='softmax')(previous_layer)
reshape=layers.Reshape((256*256,9))(out)
```

and this works but I am not sure if this implementation is correct because of the multiplication of image size how can a prediction be made and how to map the labels? My data is heavily imbalanced but still it shows accuracy around 0.995

Answer (score 1):

If your target one-hot vectors were: [[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]], then they should be [0, 1, 2] to use sparse cross entropy.

If your target shape was (256, 256, 8) then its shape should be (256, 256).

I would advice to run `model.summary()` to see the shapes.

Comment: Hi. i could understand this. But i am confused in terms of 3d vectors. My one hot encoding is a 3d vector of shape given above what will be the shape of it for sparse?

Comment: @shankarram was your target shape (256, 256, 8) ? Did you classify every pixel between 8 classes ?

Comment: Yeah for one_hot encoding the target shape is (256,256,8). the classes are based on the last channel and yeah each channel is a representation of each class

Comment: Hi I have a small question. if the target shape is (256,256) I am getting shape errors between target and output. should i do a target like this (256*256)?

Comment: @shankarram no. I would advice to run `model.summary()` and to see the shapes

Comment: I edited the question because I tried the one which you suggested and it didnot work and also the one which works am not sure if that is correct

Answer (score 0):

If there are n classes in your label, your train_label must be having a single label vector with (0-n) integers representing the classes of the vector for a single input vector. The output vector size must be n for sparse_categorical_crossentropy.

For example, in your case , as your input mask is (256,256,8) , you should convert it to (256,256,1) with 8 different integers across pixels. Obviously this method will eat up classes which are overlapping, for which you have to be using one hot encoded categorical cross entropy only. The output for sparse categorical cross entropy must be (256,256,8)

Answer (score 0):

In short, I think you do have the correct implementation.
As the others have stated; when you switch from Cross-categorical entropy to SPARSE cross categorical entropy, you need to change your input from a one-hot encoded array to a simple vector where each number is the class number.  I think the confusion is that with in the model itself, the output still needs to be the same shape, just as you have it, and of course this is why it works (256*256,9).  IF you want to move to an output shape of  (256*256,) then in fact you are needing to head to a regression approach and naturally, Categorical Anything is no longer appropriate.